# Java Blocking Queue why we have notifyall in enqueue with condition if queue.size==0?

Tags: java, queue

Here is a simple implementation:

```
  public synchronized void enqueue(Object item)throws InterruptedException  {
while(this.queue.size() == this.limit) {
  wait();
}
if(this.queue.size() == 0) {
  notifyAll();
}
this.queue.add(item);}
```

Comment: (One point that causes some confusion is that `notifyAll` does not remove the lock while executing unlike `wait`. It makes sense to put it before the action, as after an exception it will still have notified which may be important if there was a partial update.)

Answer (score 1):

Because if you look at a typical dequeue, it looks like this

```
public synchronized Object dequeue() throws InterruptedException 
{ 
    while (this.queue.size() == 0) { 
        wait();  // look here
    } 
    if (this.queue.size() == this.limit) { 
        notifyAll(); 
    } 

    return this.queue.remove(0); 
}
```

It is to notify the locks waiting while queue size is 0.

Comment: But shouldn't the notifyAll be after the remove statement? Why is it before the remove?